# Handling Daylight saving time in Google Calendar API

Tags: java, date, google-api, google-calendar-api

Google provides the support for showing time on the calendar events according to DST. However, when I get these events from the 
[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/), I get events with different time in json, even though on the UI they all have the same time, but the are on the different dates. Here is an example of it:

I created an event on 2017-10-17 with time **16:00-17:00**(local time).

```
start={dateTime=2017-10-17T14:00:00.000Z}
```

And another event is created on 2017-11-14 with time **16:00-17:00**(local time).

```
start={dateTime=2017-11-14T15:00:00.000Z}
```

Between these two dates we had a DST time switch. However, that was in my timezone(Eastern European Time Zone). Google returns dates in UTC(we have 'Z' at the ending of date).

How does it happen that Google returns different time in UTC for the same time that is shown on UI? 
I have some problems with handling that on my backend due to not having clear understanding when Google applied DST to time or not.

Comment: Eastern European Time is UTC+3 in the summer and UTC+2 in winter. So your events at 16:00 local time should have been 13:00 UTC and 14:00 UTC respectively. Are you sure you're using the correct local time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you noticed that Europe switched to [Central European Time on Sunday 29 Oct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe)?

That should account for one hour difference.

When you created first event on 2017-10-17 with time 16:00-17:00 it gets converted to UTC using offset `-02:00`.

However, second event was converted using offset `-01:00`.

Comment: Does UTC switch as well?

Comment: Nope, UTC is kept same. But you created event using local time, so when converted to UTC you will see difference between switch and afterwards.

Comment: Does it mean that google always uses UTC in the API without adding dst duration, but when I create an event, it uses the current DST rules in terms of showing?

Comment: General rule is, machines always talk in UTC, humans in local time.

Comment: What was exact string used in calendar API to create event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158384/discussion-between-dvelopp-and-rkosegi).